# How to assign a keyboard shortcut to a bat file that restarts a service?

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to know if it's possible to assign a keyboard shortcut to run a bat file as administrator, without using any software.

Comment: Pretty sure shortcuts in .lnk files will only work if the shortcut is in the Start Menu, on the Taskbar, or on the Desktop.. Is that still the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this only over a shortcut.Check [`shortcutJS.bat`](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/shortcutJS.bat).It can create a shortcut from command line and set admin permissions and

```
call shortcutJS.bat -linkfile "serv.lnk" -target "%cd%\serv.bat" -hotkey "ALT+CTRL+S" -adminpermissions yes
```

where the `serv.bat` is the bat you want to execute and is in the same directory (creation of the shortcut requires full path).

Comment: Ok, thanks, but the keyboard key to execute the serv.lnk doesn't work.

Comment: Is the `CTRL+ALT+S` assigned to other shortcut? Just tested this and key combination works...

Comment: I tested the CTRL+ALT+g before i create the serv.lnk, and that's return nothing, then I create the serv.lnk using this shortcut CTRL+ALT+g, and it's the some thing

Comment: @Yacino - open the created shortcut with right click->proprties->shortcut and see if there's something in the `shortcut key`.If the keys are there , the issue is outside the script.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut to your script on the desktop and set a shortcut key for the shortcut using standard properties window.

If you need administrator's privileges, you may create a wrapper script like this:

```
runas /user:Administrator your_original_script.bat
```

and point the shortcut to it instead.